# 3D plotting in Python

Tags: python, 3d, plot

What are my options for 3D plotting in Python?

*It also must be redistributable.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're asking for reccomendations, rather than just what modules are available...

Personally, I mostly use [Mayavi/Mlab/TVTK](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/docs/development/html/mayavi/index.html).  It's essentially a higher level interface to [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/).  It's available under a BSD-style license (If I recall correctly...), so it should be freely re-distributable.  If you're visualizing scientific data, it's an excellent choice.

For simpler 3D plots, [matplotlib's Axes3D](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html) is quite nice. Take a look at the 3D examples (towards the bottom) on the [matplotlib gallery page](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html).  However, it's not well suited to visualize volumetric data or more complex surfaces.

Naturally, those aren't the only options, but they're the two I would reccomend.

If you want to drop down to a lower level, there's always [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/), too.

At any rate, hopefully that points you in the right direction...

Answer (score 3):

One more variant is Python interface to [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net). This is GPL library with large set of 2D and 3D plotting graphics types.